# How can I make a button to show a number in the phone dialer

Tags: android, phone-call

I need to call the dialer and paste on it a string.

```
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

This way it starts calling the number. I don´t want it to start calling just to send that number to the default dialer app.

like this

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Use `ACTION_DIAL` for your `Intent` action:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel:123456789")));
```

Comment: Thanks both I read the documentation but it seems i missed it.

Answer (score 1):

**use** :

```
    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:123456789"));
    startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: Thanks both I read the documentation but it seems i missed it.